# Chrome on Windows 7 and WOFF vs. WOFF2 rendering

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, windows-7, woff, woff2

I recently attempted to automatically convert a WOFF encoding of a font to WOFF2. On Windows 8 and Mac OS 10.12, WOFF2 renders close enough between Chrome 60, IE 11, and Firefox 55. WOFF2 renders very badly in Chrome on Windows 7, but WOFF doesn't seem to suffer from the same problems. WOFF2 in Firefox appears to render correctly.

Mac OS 10.12, Safari

[image: Mac OS 10.12, Safari]

Windows 7, Chrome 60

[image: Windows 7, Chrome 60]

Notice how the 1 and 7 are being moved down slightly.

-webkit-font-smoothing is set to antialiasing.

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Converting a WOFF to a WOFF2 shouldn't change anything about the font: they're both simply "zipped" versions of a TTF or OTF font. Any chance you can add a code example with the WOFF and WOFF2 so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @RoelN https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/04/woff-2-0-what-why-and-whats-next/ has "This makes a range of improvements based on removing unnecessary data, using lengths instead of offsets, and variable length number encoding." as differences besides compression. In an old talk by the W3C (2017) https://www.w3.org/Talks/2017/font-level-up/#woff2-glyf-loca hints at differences too, but I don't remember the actual specifics.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I stand corrected! If that causes the "7" to shift down, it's not as lossless as it promises. Did you file a bug over at the Chromium project?